# How do I create a dataset from a matrix using SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I create a dataset like this with SQL?

```
a   100
b   100
b   200
c   100
c   300
d   200
d   300
```

From a table built up as a matrix like this:

```
alfa 100 200 300
a     1   0   0
b     1   1   0
c     1   0   1
d     0   1   1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to unpivot data is not to use the UNPIVOT function.

Avoid UNION where possible it can be extremely inefficient.

'CROSS APPLY with VALUES' is an excellent method, there are plenty of examples on line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you mean, but let's start here:

```
CREATE TABLE matrix (
    alfa CHAR(1),
    [100] BIT,
    [200] BIT,
    [300] BIT
)

INSERT INTO matrix
SELECT 'a', 1, 0, 0
UNION
SELECT 'b', 1, 1, 0
UNION
SELECT 'c', 1, 0, 1
UNION
SELECT 'd', 0, 1, 1

SELECT * FROM matrix

DROP TABLE matrix
```

Results:

```
/------------------------\
| alfa | 100 | 200 | 300 |
|------+-----+-----+-----|
| a    |  1  |  0  |  0  |
| b    |  1  |  1  |  0  |
| c    |  1  |  0  |  1  |
| d    |  0  |  1  |  1  |
\------------------------/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
declare @Table table (alfa char(10), c100 Int, C200 int, c300 int)
insert into @Table values
('a',     1,   0,   0)
,('b',     1,   1,   0)
,('c',     1,   0,   1)
,('d',     0,   1,   1);

SELECT alfa, 100 as Val FROM @Table WHERE c100<>0
UNION ALL SELECT alfa, 200 as val FROM @Table  WHERE C200<>0
UNION ALL SELECT alfa, 300 as val FROM @Table  WHERE c300<>0
```